# Can't access nested JSON with react & hooks. TypeErrors

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-hooks

#### JSON

This is how the json object looks in state.

```
{ 
  "gender": "male",
  "name": {
    "title":"Mr."
    "first":"Mike",
    "last": "Wazowski"
  },
  ...
}
```

#### The React

```
const App = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("https://randomuser.me/api")
      .then((response) => {
        const info = response.data.results[0];
        setUser(info);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, []);
```

Accessing the first lvl data works fine

```
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello, {user.gender}</h1> 
      <h1>Hello, {user.email}</h1> 
    </div>
  )
```

Calling object returns Err: Objects are not valid as a React child

```
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello, {user.name}</h1>
    </div>
  )
```

Calling nested data returns TypeError: user.name undefined error

```
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello, {user.name.first}</h1>
    </div>
  )
```

Why can I can access 'first level' data like gender, but not 'second-level' data like name.first?

Do I need some special syntax I'm unaware of?

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "json object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: on the last block of code try `{user['name']['first']}`. I think it understands name and `first` as variables?

Comment: @Andreas thanks for the link. So I should JSON.parse(resp.data.results[0]) so that it becomes an object literal?

Comment: I'm not fluent in `axios` things... Check the content of `response.data`/`response.data.results`. If it's a string you might have to parse it first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your errors happen at different time - you initialize your object as an empty array, so you can access fist level fields (which will be undefined), but not their fields (hence user.name undefined). Then you populate your data and `user.name` becomes an object and you can't just render in the DOM, so you get `Objects are not valid as a React child`. To solve this problem just add a null check -   `<h1>Hello, {user.name && user.name.first}</h1>`

Comment: To build on this, you can also pass a nested empty object in to `useState` as the default object. Something like `const [user, setUser] = React.useState({name: {first: ''}});`

Comment: Should I initialize the state as 'null'?  The null check did solve the problem though!

Comment: If you initialize the state as null, you'll have to null check all your fields, which is an option of course, but might be laborious. Or go with the @JimJ suggestion and use a dummy object. Whichever suites you best

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the problem with your code is that you're trying to work with your `response.data.results[0]` without converting it to a JavaScript Object. That is the response from the API is a JSON and you need to convert it to a JS Object.

Can you try parsing your `response.data.results[0]` JSON into an Object before using it?

This should work:

```
const info = JSON.parse(response.data.results[0]);
```

Comment: Just tried it. Got back TypeError: user.name is undefined

Comment: Ok, can you do `console.log(info)` and share it with us?

Comment: Nadia's null check worked without having to Parse. I'm curious as to why that is, if you'd still like to see the console output let me know.

Comment: Oh, glad you found a solution. :)